# Cannot resolve method 'getTemplateAsync' in 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'

Tags: android

I have an error on this line
Template template = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getTemplateAsync();

The error:
Cannot resolve method 'getTemplateAsync' in 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
Also it cannot resolve Template too.

here is my Firebase dependencies in gradle

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
```

and

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 32
        resValue("bool", "test_only", "true")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0' 
}
```

Am I missing any Firebase library in dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: You're right, that's not [one of the methods on `FirebaseRemoteConfig`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig). What makes you think there is a `getTemplateAsync` method at all?

Comment: `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0` has `getTemplateAsync` to modify remote config programatically. But, of course, `getTemplateAsync` is not part of Android Firebase Remote Config. https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc Please check https://github.com/firebase/snippets-java/tree/master/admin

Comment: @ocos Thanks, Adding `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0` did fix my problem.